# How can I sort a date in format: day/month/year hour:min:sec

Tags: python, sorting

Solved: Not sure why this is now on hold, Damian Yerrick helped solved issue and it seemed pretty clear to him and me.  Thanks!

Edit: Someone mentioning using datetime, but I am not understanding how to incorporate this with sorting the entire list as one, when I split apart each single tuple:

I'm a little confused how to sort this, would I need to split it apart?  Right now sorts only by date.  Here is the format:

(31/03/2016 19:42:28, value)

```
def sortDB(tupleList):
    dtList = []

    for tuple in tupleList:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tuple[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        dtList.append(dt)

    #Not sure how to get to here... AND keep the same date format I had in the beginning as I don't want it to change
    sortedKeyList = sorted(tupleList, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Parse your dates using the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Well I got around the format error, but I have no clue how this is helping me sort.  What it spits back is in no way in order.

Comment: Can you provide some actual example data? Is the example above a `tuple` containing a `datetime` object and a value or a `str`?

Comment: I guess it is sorting, but I don't see how I move from this to sorting where I need the original date/value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting in Python works on the basis of a "key" derived from each item. It translates each item into a key, sorts the items by their keys, and then discards the keys, leaving the original items. Python normally uses the item itself as the key, and for tuples, that's the same as using the elements of the tuple with their normal comparison behavior. You'll want to make a function that overrides the default key derivation and then tell Python to use that function when sorting the original items.

```
def getDateFromTuple(tuple):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(tuple[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

sortedKeyList = sorted(tupleList, key=getDateFromTuple, reverse=True)
```

This way, Python's `sorted()` function will call the `key` function (in this case `getDateFromTuple()`) on each element of the sequence being sorted (`tupleList`). This causes Python to sort the elements of `tupleList` by the parsed dates rather than by the literal strings in each tuple.

For another explanation of `key`, see [the section "Key Functions" in Python Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) and the [documentation for `sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: Hmm I will try this, although it is a bit confusing.  I understand the getDateFromTuple function and how it operates on that specific element. But it is the idea that the key in sorted would be a tuple element of the tupleList without me having to indicate it.  I would think you would have to say key=getDataFromTuple(tupleList[i]).  Thanks!

Comment: @Zak44 The `sorted()` function calls the `key` function (in this case `getDateFromTuple()`) on each element of `tupleList`.

Comment: @Zak44 It adds the `(tupleList[i])` for you because it has its own local `i` that the caller (that is, your program) doesn't see.